# Compass/Middleman image-url isn't working

Tags: compass-sass, middleman

I'm currently working with Middleman to build up a new page, but now the image-url helper doesn't seem to be working.

In my config.rb I have:

```
#Use relative URLs   
activate :relative_assets

set :css_dir, 'stylesheets' 
set :js_dir, 'javascripts'
set :images_dir, 'images'
```

In my applications.css.sass I have this:

```
body
  background: image_url("background.png")
```

The background image is in images/background but Middleman doesn't find/load that image. It just puts this out:

```
body {
  background: url("../images/background.png");
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well I was under the impression that I can put background in the "images/backgrounds/" folder and Middlemand/Compass would pull it out of that folder. But it isn't doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Use relative URLs   
activate :relative_assets
```

I believe this is within the "build" configurations so it won't have any effect on your working file that you are viewing in middleman local server.

for me using this works "/images/hp/wmn.png"

I guess you just need to figure out the write path to your asset, as a temporary solution you can use an absolute link starting with your local server address
    //0.0.0.0:4567/ for mac or 
    //localhost:4567/ for windows

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: url("/images/background.png");
}
```